# How Can I Align all of the Cells of my Table to \RaggedRight

Tags: alignment, ragged2e, xltabular

I created this table in LaTeX by using the `xltabular` package:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{X X X X X X X}
\toprule
Activity & \multicolumn{2}{X}{1. Feb 10, 2022} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{2. April 26, 2022} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{3. June 6, 2022}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
& Score & Goal & Score & Goal & Score & Goal\\
\midrule\endfirsthead
\toprule
Activity & \multicolumn{2}{X}{1.} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{2. April 26, 2022} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{3. June 6, 2022}\\
\midrule\endhead
Push-ups & 20\newline Level 1 & 25\newline Level 2 & 29\newline Level 2 & 40\newline Level 4 & 30\newline Level 3 & 40\newline Level 4\\
\addlinespace
Crunches & 24\newline Level 1 & 30\newline Level 2 & 40\newline Level 2 & 30\newline Level 3 & 26\newline Level 3 & 40\newline Level 3\\
\addlinespace
Plank & 1:00\newline Level 1 & 1:30\newline Level 1 & 1:13\newline Level 1 & 1:30\newline Level 2 & 2:01\newline Level 3 & 3:00\newline Level 3\\
\addlinespace
Vertical jump & 40 & 50 & 36 & 50 & 40 & 50\\
\addlinespace
Sit, reach, and hold & 16 & 17 & 16 & 17 & 17 & 18\\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
```

[image]

By default, the text in all of the cells is justified.
I want to change it to \RaggedRight from the `ragged2e` package.
How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome! You can use this in your preamble: `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}` and use the Y column type for your table.

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `X` column type so that it (a) typesets its contents ragged-right and (b) allows for variable widths. (In the table below, the first column is about 18% wider than the remaining six.)

Note that there's an oversight in your code: Instead of

```
\multicolumn{2}{X}{1. Feb 10, 2022}
```

it should be

```
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}X}{1. Feb 10, 2022}`
```

and likewise for the other `\multicolumn` directives. Actually, an even simpler solution is available: It's permissible to use the `l` column type since the header text lines are sufficiently short.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} L{1.15} *{6}{L{0.975}} @{}}

\toprule
Activity & \multicolumn{2}{l}{1. Feb 10, 2022} 
         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{2. April 26, 2022} 
         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{3. June 6, 2022}\\
         \cmidrule(lr){2-3} 
         \cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
         \cmidrule(l){6-7}
         & Score & Goal 
         & Score & Goal 
         & Score & Goal \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot


Push-ups & 20\newline Level 1 & 25\newline Level 2 
         & 29\newline Level 2 & 40\newline Level 4 
         & 30\newline Level 3 & 40\newline Level 4 \\
\addlinespace
Crunches & 24\newline Level 1 & 30\newline Level 2 
         & 40\newline Level 2 & 30\newline Level 3 
         & 26\newline Level 3 & 40\newline Level 3 \\
\addlinespace
Plank    & 1:00\newline Level 1 & 1:30\newline Level 1 
         & 1:13\newline Level 1 & 1:30\newline Level 2 
         & 2:01\newline Level 3 & 3:00\newline Level 3 \\
\addlinespace
Vertical jump & 40 & 50 
              & 36 & 50 
              & 40 & 50 \\
\addlinespace
Sit, reach, and hold 
              & 16 & 17 
              & 16 & 17 
              & 17 & 18 \\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```